# How to collapse a data-role when another is opened with Mobile JQuery?

Tags: jquery, mobile

im using Mobile JQuery to create a site and I have the code below, however when I can open all of the collapsible menues, but I want it so that when I open another menu, the previous one closes.
Here is the code that I have so far

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3>My Data</h3>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#aberdeen" data-transition="pop">Liverpool</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aberdeen" data-transition="pop">Manchester</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aberdeen" data-transition="pop">Sheffield</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3>More Data</h3>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#aberdeen" data-transition="pop">York</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aberdeen" data-transition="pop">London</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aberdeen" data-transition="pop">Newcastle</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```